# respondsToSelector Always Returns NO for setPinTintColor

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9

With iOS 9 you can now set custom map pin colors. As I have an app that runs from 8.x and up and I need to make sure the user has at least iOS 9 if they want to customize the pin color.  I am doing the check as follows which is always producing NO under iOS 9.

```
-(BOOL)isVersionHigherThan_8_4
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinTest;

    if ([pinTest respondsToSelector:@selector(setPinTintColor:)])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;

}
```

I know setPinTintColor is working as I can set and use it just fine under iOS 9.  Why does this test produce a NO even under version 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pinTest;
```

pinTest is nil, sending messages to nil will produce: nil, 0 or NO.

So instantiate the object first.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!